# Conway's Game of Life - Neighbour-counting issue

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a "game of life" working in python, but I can't seem to get the neighbour-counting aspect of the program working properly. I'm trying to use multiple if-statements to avoid any "out-of-bounds" errors in the array, and that's been working. However the program is finding "neighbours" where none exist, leading to the program generating living cells all over the place when it really shouldn't. Any help would be appreciated, I'm really stuck on this.

Extra info: The list is 10x10, and the cells check all eight directions.

Thanks

```
def checkNeighbours(newWorld, row, column):
   neighboursCount = 0
   if(column > 0):
       if(newWorld[row][column-1] == ALIVE): #checks cell to left
           neighboursCount = neighboursCount + 1
   if(row < 9):
       if(newWorld[row+1][column] == ALIVE): #checks cell below
           neighboursCount = neighboursCount + 1
   if(row < 9 and column < 9):
       if(newWorld[row+1][column+1] == ALIVE): #checks cell to bottom right
           neighboursCount = neighboursCount + 1
   if(row < 9 and column > 0):
       if(newWorld[row+1][column-1] == ALIVE): #checks cell to bottom left
           neighboursCount = neighboursCount + 1
   if(column < 9):
       if(newWorld[row][column+1] == ALIVE): #checks cell to right
           neighboursCount = neighboursCount + 1
   if(row > 0 and column > 0):
       if(newWorld[row-1][column-1] == ALIVE): #checks cell to top left
           neighboursCount= neighboursCount + 1
   if(row > 0):
       if(newWorld[row-1][column] == ALIVE): #checks cell above
           neighboursCount = neighboursCount + 1
   if(row != 0 and column != 9):
       if(newWorld[row-1][column+1] == ALIVE): #checks cell to top right
           neighboursCount = neighboursCount + 1
   return(neighboursCount)


def birthsAndDeaths(newWorld, row, column, neighboursCount):
   if(neighboursCount == 3 and newWorld[row][column] == DEAD):
       return(ALIVE)
   elif(neighboursCount == 2 or neighboursCount == 3 and newWorld[row][column] == ALIVE):
       return(ALIVE)
   elif(neighboursCount <= 1):
       return(DEAD)
   elif(neighboursCount >= 4):
       return(DEAD) 

def turnChanger(turn, newWorld):
   turn = turn + 1
   row = 0
   while (row < SIZE): # Each iteration accesses a single row 
       column = 0
       while (column < SIZE):  # Each iteration accesses a single column in the given row
           neighboursCount = checkNeighbours(newWorld, row, column)
           print(neighboursCount, "for cell", row, column)
           newWorld[row][column] = birthsAndDeaths(newWorld, row, column, neighboursCount)
           column = column + 1
       row = row + 1  
   return(turn, newWorld)

def start():
   choice = 0
   choice = selection()
   world = worldChooser(choice)

   oldWorld = []
   newWorld = []
   turn = 0

   oldWorld = world
   newWorld = world
   
   turn, newWorld = turnChanger(turn, newWorld)
   display(turn, oldWorld, newWorld)   
   
   world = newWorld
start()
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the code; especially including how `newWorld` is created. This could be the classic issue of writing to the same world that you're reading from.

Comment: @Carcigenicate for sure, sorry to miss that
```def start():
    choice = 0
    choice = selection()
    world = worldChooser(choice)

    oldWorld = []
    newWorld = []
    turn = 0

    oldWorld = world
    newWorld = world
    
    turn, newWorld = turnChanger(turn, newWorld)
    display(turn, oldWorld, newWorld)   
    
    world = newWorld
start()```

this is the main start option that generates the worlds, the user picks from 1 of 6 possible base worlds to generate

The newWorld/oldWorlds are used to display simultaneously to show the world before and after a change

Comment: The code at the top is far more complicate than it needs to be though, a double `for` loop that uses `min` and `max` to ensure the index doesn't go out of bounds would reduce that whole chunk down to like 4-6 lines (I'd estimate).

Comment: Please post that in the question. I'm pretty sure I'm right about the issue, but it's hard to tell from reading unformatted code in the comments.

Comment: @Carcigenicate added. Sorry about the trouble, I'm pretty new to this website

Comment: Why did you use `> 0` and `< 9` *most* of the time except once where you used `!= 0` and `!= 9`? I don't know if it actually makes a difference, but that's where I would start to look.

Comment: There isn't enough detail yet, so I can't post an answer. I'll paste what I was going to post as an answer though: [here](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/d3ff27b61b8d3ef3685c56084ac15ace).

Comment: @mkrieger1 that was just because I decided to change it to >/< later on but missed the != there

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you for the info, I'll try and implement that

Comment: Just to elaborate, since it's critical to the simulation: say you have two cells next to each other. You check cell 1, and determine that it should go from dead to alive. You then check cell 2. If you update the world as you're reading from it (which you're doing here), cell 2 will see cell 1 as alive; but this is wrong. Until the entire world has been checked, cell 2 should still see cell 1 as dead, since cell 1 isn't alive until the next tick starts. With how you're currently managing state, cell 2 will see cell 1 as alive as soon as cell 1 is updated.

Comment: The way I handle state is to have two worlds created separately at the beginning. After every tick, you swap them (`tmp = oldWorld; oldWorld = newWorld; newWorld = tmp`, or the standard `oldWorld, newWorld = newWorld, oldWorld` idiom specific to Python). This makes it so they remain independent, different objects throughout the program.

Comment: As mentioned by Carcigenicate, function checkNeighbours can be simplified to `def checkNeighbours(newWorld, row, column): return sum(1 if newWorld[r][c] == ACTIVE else 0 for r, c in get_neighbors(row, column))` where get_neighbors is `def get_neighbors(row, column):  return [(r, c) for r in range(row-1, row+2) for c in range(column-1, column+2) if 0 <= r <= 9 and 0 <= c <= 9 and (r, c) != (row, column)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is right in the `birthsAndDeaths` function, in this line:

```
elif(neighboursCount == 2 or neighboursCount == 3 and newWorld[row][column] == ALIVE):
```

Because of order of operations, you must ensure that the `or` is evaluated first, so use parentheses around that section.

```
elif((neighboursCount == 2 or neighboursCount == 3) and newWorld[row][column] == ALIVE):
```

Any `and` operators are evaluated before the `or`, so in your code it ends up setting the cell to alive any time there are 2 neighbors next to any cell.

With your current code, say we have 2 neighbors next to a dead cell, it will go

```
elif(neighboursCount == 2 or neighboursCount == 3 and newWorld[row][column] == ALIVE):
```

then

```
elif(true or false and false):
```

then

```
elif(true or false):
```

then

```
elif(true):
```

And the body of the `elif` returns an `ALIVE` result.

Using parentheses around the `or` causes the contents of those parentheses to be evaluated first. In this the content is one `or` operation. Using the parentheses means that we will get

```
elif((neighboursCount == 2 or neighboursCount == 3) and newWorld[row][column] == ALIVE):
```

then

```
elif((true or false) and false):
```

then

```
elif(true and false):
```

then

```
elif(false):
```

This is the solution to the specific problem you are asking about here. However, Carcigenicate has pointed out another major issue. If you try fixing that and you still have trouble you can post a new question.